# Cisco ISR 4000 series with SM-X Layer 2/3 module

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-isr

I have a Cisco SM-X-16G4M2X Layer 2/3 Service Module installed in an ISR 4000 series router, and I would like to configure its ports as level 2 in a vlan, and then configure that vlan with an IP address, as is described here:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/interfaces/sm/software/configuration/guide/SMX16G4M2X-book.html

My IOS version is 16.12.03, newer than IOS XE Gibraltar 16.12.1a release required to configure the Cisco SM-X-16G4M2X.

However, I cannot define this command (API offers it, but its use returns an error):

```
interface vlan vlan_id
```

My license is the base one.

The error is:

```
Router(config)# interface vlan 24
--------------------------^
syntax error: element does not exist
```

And the

> sh diag all eeprom

for this module is shown as:

```
SPA EEPROM data for subslot 1/0:

Product Identifier (PID) : SM-X-16G4M2X
Version Identifier (VID) : V01
PCB Serial Number : XXXXXXXXXXX
Hardware Revision : 1.0
CLEI Code : xxxxxxxxxx
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Many thanks

Comment: It would probably help if you would add the exact error message you're receiving to this question.

Comment: I have added. It doesn´t accept "Vlan24", "vlan24", "Vlan 24" or "vlan 24".

Comment: Do you actually see that the board is installed and working in the router? Also, your IOS version has been EoS for nearly five years, and it will be completely EoL in a few months, so it is past time to upgrade.

Comment: By the way, 3.16.03 was already Eos (August 1, 2017) _before_ IOS XE Gibraltar 16.12.1 was released (31-JUL-2019, and it has even been EoS for over a year), so your statement about your IOS being newer is incorrect. You really need to get something newer.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. My IOS was already updated to 16.12.03, but it is also failing. I´ve just corrected my mistake in the post.

Comment: Have you determined that the board is working correctly in the router? Can you see the interfaces? Does it show up in the module and/or hardware inventory?

Comment: Interfaces are shown, and I am able to configure with swtichport in vlan 24. I have added the output of the hardware inventory for that module, in my post (I´ve replaced the serial number and CLEI code). The router has been recently adquired and has never been used before.

Comment: We need the full version, inventory, and config. Has it been reloaded since installing the module? Is there a NIM-ES in it as well? Has the vlan been defined in the main configuration?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

License was not properly set. A reload was also required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an SVI, I don't think that you will be able to - from the link that you've provided, I've extracted the following sentence:

"Once a range of interfaces has been bundled, any VLAN interface configuration change must be done only on a port channel. Otherwise, the interfaces will get suspended."

This means that you must create a port-channel with a sub-interface with the specific VLAN that you want to assign the IP address to - example below:

Interface Port-channel3.101 -# Here you define the subinterface ID

encapsulation dot1q 101 -# here you define the VLAN ID

ip address 10.10.101.1 255.255.255.0

interface gig1/0/1 #/ or whatever your module is/
channel-group 3 mode active

Hope this helps.

Best regards

Comment: But I don´t want an aggregated port or define a ROAS (Router-On-A-Stick) with subinterfaces. My connections will be to two different CEs, in level 2, and then the router will add these ports to a VLAN with a unique IP. Both CEs and my router will belong to the same /29 network.

Comment: Those two different CEs will have to see each other on layer 2 only? I do not fully understand the purpose and what are you actually trying to achieve here, so if you put some more details, maybe I can be of some use. If you simply want to have a designated VLAN that has a /29 subnet on it so the 2 CEs can communicate with one another and the gateway/your router/, then I do not see any reason not to use router on a stick.

Comment: If you do have switch modules, you can define VLANs and SVIs on them only, not on the router itself. Like Ron mentioned previously, maybe if this doesn't work you should have a look at the platform and does it recognize the switch module. Also, take under consideration that if the module is not hot swap, maybe you will need to reboot the router in order for it to come online, so do some research on that and you can comment here so we can see what the case is, but anyway, only on the switch modules will you be able to add SVIs and VLAN definitions like on a switch.